# What is the policy on "operator" tags?

Tags: support, tags

What is our policy on "operator" tags.  Tags whose names are operators.  So far I have only came across two but it is nice to know.

1. [is](/questions/tagged/is)
2. [andand](/questions/tagged/andand)

Comment: Don't know about "policy", but they sure seem pointless to me. Are there any `is` experts out there, watching the tag?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

(Not an active member of SO, so you can take my post with a pinch of salt. Or waffles, if you prefer)

[andand](/questions/tagged/andand), yes. It's a library--we have tons of library tags. Though it's not that popular it seems, so really the tag isn't necessary. Yet.

[is](/questions/tagged/is), no. It has gone down the memory hole now.

Unless an operator is particularly problematic (eg JS `for in`), I doubt that we need a tag for it. The tag should be useful for filtering the question. There's no such thing as an expert in the "is" operator.

Comment: Awww, man; I was hoping we had some `is`experts lurking!

Comment: That's not true! I'm totally in expert in usage of the equality operator!

Comment: @Kobobby Well, now that one *does* need some experts!